# My app crashes when I click on listview

Tags: android, listview

My app crashes when I click on a `ListView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listview;
    private NavDrawerAdapter navDrawerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);
        listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        navDrawerAdapter= new NavDrawerAdapter(this);
        listview.setAdapter(navDrawerAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(position==0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    selectedItem(position);
}
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat

Comment: My guess : you did not declare the login activity in your manifest. Anyway, post your logcat if you want some help

Answer (score -1):

```
      @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       if(position==0){ 
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       } 

       selectedItem(position); 
      }
```

The parameter to start activity is wrong. But still with that code, compiler shouldn't allow you. 
Is it crash or compiler error?

Comment: Did you read my description,,, and to further help post your crash log.